# How to estimate stability and stiffness of a system of coupled ODEs?

Tags: linear-algebra, ode, stability, differential-equations, stiffness

I'm running into issues with Python/Julia ODE solvers requiring prohibitively small timesteps to evolve a system of 4 coupled ODEs (the order of magnitude of the state variables and time unit span ~40-50 orders of magnitude). Interestingly if I use a simple explicit Euler approach then I can get past the stiffness at early times (where the general adaptive solvers get stuck) and roughly match theoretical expectations at later times.

Apart from the technical coding details, I have noticed that it is common to talk about the mathematical stability and stiffness of ODE systems. Is there a standard way to calculate the expected stability and stiffness given a set of coupled ODEs, initial conditions, integration timescales, input parameters, and maybe a solver algorithm?

For what it's worth, my system of 4 coupled ODEs looks like

$$\frac{dM_1}{dt} = g(t) - c(t,M_1,E)M_1(t) + w(t)M_3(t) - e(M_1,E)h(M_1,E)E(t)$$

$$\frac{dM_2}{dt} = c(t,M_1,E)M_1(t) - s(t)M_2(t) - w(t)M_3(t)$$

$$\frac{dM_3}{dt} = s(t)M_2(t)$$

$$\frac{dE}{dt} = g(t)v(t) - c(t,M_1,E)E(t) + b(t)w(t)M_3(t) - h(M_1,E)E(t)$$

where the various lettered functions are input parameters that depend on time and/or state variables. I know this isn't enough for doing stability/stiffness analysis but it's a start. I'd appreciate any pedagogical references, even for much simpler illustrative systems -- I vaguely remember this involves linear algebra and eigendecomposition but it's been so long since undergrad.

Comment: Have you computed the eigenvalues of the Jacobian of the right hand side?

Comment: No but I would love to explore that idea further for different assumptions about the input parameters. Does that need to be done manually or is there a standard package in scipy that can return the Jacobian given a set of ODEs (or matrix of the RHS)? Can you please point me to any simple pedagogical python examples?

Comment: I don't know scipy, so can't help.

Comment: You could use [sympy](https://www.sympy.org) to describe the RHS and the Jacobian symbolically, then use the function sympy.lambdify to generate python code that evaluates them and produces numpy arrays, and finally call [numpy.linalg.eig](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html).